# Angular 4 Datefromat Pipe IE error

Tags: angular, date-format

I need to format a date in  `'dd.MM.yyyy, hh:mm'` (standard German format). This works fine in Chrome, FF but doesn't work in IE 11!

Example:

```
import { Component }          from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <p>{{today | date: 'dd.MM.yyyy, hh:mm' }}</p>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  today: number = Date.now();
  title = 'Tour of Heroes';
}
```

In Chrome, etc it outputs: `16.10.2017, 03:32`

In IE 11: `03:10/16/2017 3:36:51 PM`

What works is `dd.MM.yyyy, HH` which outputs `16.10.2017, 15:00`across all browsers, but why the mintues?

Which makes no sense to me. Accordiong to the documenation `mm` shoud output the minutes.

Demo App:
https://plnkr.co/edit/evzPXttejISsuoEDJHH5?p=preview

Dokumentation:
https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Comment: I created a bug report too: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19743 guess this matches more...

Comment: From Angular DatePipe API Documentation.
"this pipe uses the Internationalization API. Therefore it is only reliable in Chrome and Opera browsers.